# MYSQL How to select rows between previous hour and next hour from now?

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime, where-clause

I'm trying to do a query in MYSQL selecting orders where the `created_at` datetime is between the previous 3:00 in the morning and the next 3:00 in the morning.

For example: if I make that query at `2020-03-31 11:00:00`, it should show me all the orders where the `created_at` timestamp are between `2020-03-31 03:00:00` and `2020-04-01 03:00:00`.

I've tried to make this by using this query:

```
select * 
from "orders" 
where "created_at" BETWEEN cast(curdate() as datetime) + interval 3 hour 
                        and cast(curdate() as datetime) + interval 1 day + interval 3 hour
```

but that doesn't work correctly because if i execute this query between 0:00 and 3:00 in the morning (For example at `2020-03-31 00:30:00`), it won't show anything, but it should show me all the orders where the `created_at` timestamp are between `2020-03-30 03:00:00` and `2020-03-31 03:00:00`.

Any idea of how to do that? I've been trying to find a solution for 2 hours a i couldn't find the right query to do so.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60947151/edit) and include example data with expected output.

Answer (score 0):

I would do:

```
created at >= date(now()- interval 3 hour) + interval 3 hour
and created_at < date(now()- interval 3 hour) + interval 3 hour + interval 1 day
```

The logic is to offset the current date *and time* by 3 hours, remove the time component, and then add 3 hours.

Answer (score 0):

Then you could do

```
select ...
where `created_at` BETWEEN DATE_SUB(concat(CURDATE(), ' 03:00:00'), INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
                    AND concat(CURDATE(), ' 03:00:00');
```